# jQuery FadeIn() and etc are not working , browser considers that they are not function at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

in This piece of code, I want to fadeIn Elements

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
    $('div').fadeIn("2000", function () {
    })
})
```

in Google Chrome Developers part it tells me that `fadeIn()` is not a function!

what is the matter ? What can I do? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you included correctly the JQuery library, and not the `SLIM` version of it?

Comment: Readout :-   https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadein

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to add Jquery library to the end of your body before your javascript codes.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can use fadeIn function. Also, you should use the jquery selector in the correct way. Hope this sample help you.

```js
    $( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
        $( "#ContentDIV" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
            // Animation complete
        });
    });
```

```css
.test {
            background-color: grey;
            padding: 20px;
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clickme">Click Me</button>
 
<div id="ContentDIV" class="test">
    This is a test DIV
</div>
```